# how to build a restcomm conference application

Tags: restcomm

I want to build a simple conferencing application with Restcomm. I used example XMLs provided with restcomm to start conference and add participants to a conference, I needed two phone numbers to do it.
I have following questions for this:
1. Do I always need to dial a phone number to start the conference? Doesn't Restcomm provide any API to start the conference via HTTP.
2. How can I use the same application to start the conference and also add participants to conference. In the example XML with restcomm, there are two XMLs provided for conferencing (one to start the conference and other to add participant), doesn't it mean that I'll have to use two different phone numbers then for a single conference?

Comment: The question has already been answered here too:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restcomm/ZenXjJj547I